# How to share variables between callbacks in Pyspark job?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, spark-streaming

I've tried

1. global variables -- This method works.
2. Subclassing SparkContext with extra member variable, and then fetching the extra member variable through rdd.context().getMyData() in my callback -- This method failed with an error of my subclass type is not callable.

I'm also new to Spark and am wondering if there is any way to do this that is better than global variables? Or if there is a supposed way provided by Spark that I've been missing? The data I'm sharing is a separate buffer for samples in each RDD, because the Fast Fourier Transform algorithm I'm feeding samples to requires a specific count of samples, so I'm buffering samples until the buffer size reaches this specific count. Any insights and suggestions are deeply appreciated!!

My code sample:

```
limit = 64
buffer=[]
def processSamples(rdd):
     global limit
     global buffer
     lines = rdd.collect()
     for (k,v) in lines:
       if len(buffer) == limit:
           FFT(buffer)
           del buffer[:]
       buffer.append(v)
if __name__ == "__main__":
     sc = SparkContext()
     ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)
     topic = "topic1"
     ks = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092"})
     ks.foreachRDD(processSamples)
     ssc.start()
     ssc.awaitTermination()
```